# socket.io disconnect after emitting to specific client NODE javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Hello I am currently working on some kind of "Chat"-system.

Server: NodeJs with express - https
Communication: Socket.io@1.0

client:

```
var socket = io.connect();
socket.emit('HELLO', {user:'someuserid'});
socket.on('WELCOME', function(data){
    socket.emit('REGISTER', {});
});
socket.on('SIGNED', function(data){
    console.log(data.user);
    socket.emit('GO', {});
});
socket.on('message', function(data){
    console.log(data.somedata);
});
```

server:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('HELLO', function(data){
        socket.user = data.user;
        socket.emit('WELCOME', socket.user);
    });
    socket.on('REGISTER', function(data){
        console.log('room: '+socket.user);
        socket.join(socket.user);
        socket.emit('SIGNED', socket.user);
        console.log('SIGNED IN: '+socket.user);

    });
    socket.on('GO', function(data){
        //some logic happens where a list of users gets loaded
        //which is identical to the socket.user and its room
        //... loop
        io.in(partners[i].user).emit('message', { somedata: 'asd' });
    }

    socket.on('disconnect' ..... blaaa blaa)
```

So, basicly what I tried to do here is create a workaround to sending a message to a specific user by sending a message to a specific room.

this:

```
 io.in(partners[i].user).emit('message', { somedata: 'asd' });
```

and this:

```
 partners[i].socket.emit('message', { somedata: 'asd' });
```

result in the same:

```
room: 540246a3e4b0a64a28e1ec59
SIGNED IN: 540246a3e4b0a64a28e1ec59
room: 540504ba0b526b274398480e
SIGNED IN: 540504ba0b526b274398480e
to: 540246a3e4b0a64a28e1ec59
disconnected:540246a3e4b0a64a28e1ec59
```

the user registers, gets connected and wants to emit a message to specific chatpartners in the array partners[i].

once the emit is fired the user, the message is supposed to be emitted to disconnects...

what am I doing wrong?

(the script is obviously not complete.. i pasted the most important parts)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I think I have found the solution:

sometimes using google is more effort than debugging by yourself.

After scrolling through the debug log in firefox I found out that this problem actually had to do with the code inside my socket 'message' handler. A snippet that might help others to find errors with their sockets:

```
socket.on('error', function (err) {
  if (err.description) throw err.description;
  else throw err; // Or whatever you want to do
});
```

I think this is an issue in socket.io
although it was my wrong code - the socket.io errorhandler should have passed that through.

Have fun